# how can i access my .plist in my swift Game

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, plist

I wanted to access the .plist for my doodle jump clone to create the platforms but it always gives me this error

where is my mistake? Please help

gamehandler Script:

```
import Foundation

class GameHandler {
    var score:Int
    var highScore:Int
    var star:Int
    
    var levelData:NSDictionary!
    
    class var sharedInstance:GameHandler{
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = GameHandler()
        }
        
        return Singleton.instance
    }
    
    init(){
        score = 0
        highScore = 0
        star = 0
        
        
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        highScore = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "highScore")
        star = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "Stars")
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Level01", ofType: "plist"){
            if let level = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
                levelData = level
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    func saveGameStats(){
        highScore = max(score,highScore)
        
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
        userDefaults.set(highScore, forKey: "Stars")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsCwU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUsgK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NSDictionary/NSArray` in Swift. Both are *typeless* and the compiler needs the concrete type for index and key subscription.

The code source seems to be pretty old. The `Singleton/sharedInstance` detour is not necessary anymore for a long time.

This is a more contemporary version of your code. The force unwrapping of `url` and `data` is fine because the file is immutable in the application bundle and the app would't work anyway if the file is not available.

if `levelData` will never be modified declare it as constant (`let`).

In the image code snippets cast a dictionary to `[String:Any]` and an array to `[[String:Any]]`

```
import Foundation

class GameHandler {
    var score: Int
    var highScore: Int
    var star: Int
    
    var levelData: [String:Any] 
    
    static let shared = GameHandler()
    
    private init(){
        score = 0
        
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        highScore = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "highScore")
        star = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "Stars")
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Level01", withExtension: "plist")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        levelData = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
    }
    
    func saveGameStats() {
        highScore = max(score,highScore)
        
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
        userDefaults.set(highScore, forKey: "Stars") // Shouldn't it be `star`??
    }
}
```

Nevertheless I highly recommend to read the plist data into structs with `PropertyListDecoder`. This gets rid of any type casting.